# Multiple queries as record source for single form?

Tags: ms-access

I'm back with another problem. I have a form based on a query with the parameter in the WHERE clause being the combobox of the form. In the detail, it is continuous form view and shows all the matching fields for the combobox(re-queries after update of combobox). There's a textbox and a button at the footer where the user can add new entries for this data.

I need to have basically a mirror of this form right beside it -- so that they can be compared visually. I need two combo boxes side-by side in my header -- with two controls in the detail section that are populated based on the query. I considered using subform to basically create the illusion of this, but I can't have subforms with continuous form view. The idea that I was thinking was to have two queries as the form's record source:

```
Select value FROM t1 WHERE criteria = me.combo1;
select value as val2 from t1 WHERE criteria = me.combo2;
```

**Example Data (same structure):**

```
          **Friends**
    **User            friend**
  Bob              Jack
  Bob              Zach
  Bob              Mack
  John             Juan
  John             Sha'Quan
```

I would then have in the detail section a 'value' control and a 'val2' control that would be populated from different queries and criteria.

Is this possible?

Or, should I instead just have two subforms, each with a different parent key determined by the value selected in the combobox? I'd prefer it to be the way I listed, but if there is no other option, is this what I'd have to do?

Comment: "but I can't have subforms with continuous form view" why not?  You can set each subform's respective recordset to it's corresponding combobox in the parent form.

Comment: I can use two subforms and just link them so the positions, but the subforms don't behave the same way as having a single form with contonuous view. I have to scroll within the subform rather than scrolling within the form itself. What I meant to say was that I can't have subforms with a parent form thats view is set to 'continuous'

Comment: Ah I see now, theoretically I think that could be possible if you were to construct your own custom scroll bar on the main form and have it's action scroll the underlying subforms (perhaps there's an API out there) I'm just speculating really, I haven't ever actually done it myself.

Comment: I just ended up doing two subforms. It doesn't look the way that I wanted it to, but it works. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tx.*, ty.*
FROM (Select id, value FROM t1 WHERE criteria = me.combo1) As tx
LEFT JOIN (select id, value as val2 from t1 WHERE criteria = me.combo2) As ty
ON tx.ID = ty.ID
```

I had to requery the form in the after update event of the first combo.

```
SELECT x.*,
       y.*
FROM   (SELECT t1.user,
               t1.friend
        FROM   t1
        WHERE  (( ( t1.user ) = [forms]![myForm]![combo5] ))) AS x
       INNER JOIN (SELECT user,
                          friend
                   FROM   t1
                   WHERE  (( ( t1.friend ) = [forms]![myForm]![combo7] ))) AS y
               ON ( x.user = y.user )
                  AND ( x.friend = y.friend );
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is working as intended. The queries are to be based on the same table with the same field as criteria. It also prompts me for input for ty.id. Can you explain what the left join is supposed to be accomplishing here?

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to select a value from a table, t1, but with two different WHERE statements. The way to do this is to create two derived tables and link them on a common unique field. I have called the common field ID. I have added ID to the inner queries, so that should fix the error, if you have a field called id.

Comment: I don't have a field called ID, the table has a composite PK..I changed it as appropriate. The query runs, but doesn't give me the correct results. For example, if I have the same criteria selected for each query, it turns up a correct list of values for val1 and val2. If I have different criteria selected for each query, only val1 returns data

Comment: Perhaps you could post some sample data?

Comment: added some - for example with this sample data, I would like to select from a combobox 'Bob' and see all of Bob's friends. I would like an adjacent combobox where I could select 'John' and see John's friends beside it. I know this could be done with two subforms side by side, I was just wondering if it's possible to due this with one form(in continuous view)

Comment: Scott, that is not sample data. Where is the composite primary key?

Comment: User and Friend is the two part composite pk. -- What were you looking for from the sample data that I didn't provide?